# How do I prove that the range of log is $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

For a real analysis course. In the first part of the problem, I proved that $\log xy = \log x + \log y$. Here $\log x$ is defined as $\int_1^x\frac1t\mathrm dt$. Since it's a two part problem, I am assuming that will come in handy.

I am not sure how to go about this one. Do I need to show that the log function is surjective?

Here's what I did:

Suppose $u \in \mathbb{R}$ and choose $n, m$ such that $n > {u\over \log 2}$ and $m < {u\over \log 2}$. Without loss of generality, we have that for all $m > 0$, we have $2^m \in (0, \infty)$, and for $m <0$ we have $(1/2)^{\mid m \mid } = 2^m$, and for $m = 0$ we have $2^m = 1$. Then $\log 2^n = \log 2 + \log 2 + \log 2 ...$, with $n$ factors of $\log 2$ by part (a). Then $\log 2^n = n\log 2$. Similarly, $\log 2^m = m\log 2$. Then by the Intermediate Value theorem, $n\log 2 > u > m\log 2$. Thus the range of $\log$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Comment: Showing that $\log$ is surjective is precisely showing that its range is $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've proved that $\log x$ is continuous, and $\log(e)=1$ then you can show that there exists $x$ such that $\log(x)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ by using $\log xy=\log x +\log y$, and so from this you can use the intermediate value theorem to show that $\log$ attains every real number between the integers as well.

Comment: I haven't proved that log is continuous per se, but it's defined as an integral so it's a given, right?

Comment: @JohanLiebert Is $\log x$ differentiable?

Comment: How do we know $\log e=1$ by the way?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: it is not needed: $\log 1 = 0$

Comment: Yes $\log 1=0$ certainly but I don't know how that relates to my question of how we know $\log e=1$?

Comment: You don't need to use $\log e=1$, you just need to show that there exists some $x\neq 0$ such that there is a $y$ with $\log y=x$. Then $\{nx\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ will be the set you show $\log$ attains values in between by the intermediate value theorem. I just figured that showing $\log e=1$ was a common exercise in real analysis courses so might be usable by the OP.

Comment: Correct if we show $\log (1/x)=-\log x$ which isn't too hard I suppose.

Comment: @JohanLiebert the fundamental theorem of calculus will show you that $\log$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Can you show that $\log2>1/2$? What can you say then about $\log2^n$? Why is $\log x$ continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Im not going to do the homework for you but here are 3 steps :

1) prove the continuity
2) prove lim x-> +inf = +inf
3) prove lim x->0 = -infinity (use formula)

Comment: Perhaps in your setting, you shall hint that to prove 2) one can use harmonic series (if they are available to the OP)